# ggplot2 using facetwrap and multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to create a plot depicting the total number of observations and the number of observations with the variable Rating = Rated within each segment small, medium, and large. My expected output would be three graphs with one line depicting the total number of observations and one line depicting the number of observations with the variable Rated

My current code looks like this:

```
df <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date, MarketSeg) %>%
  summarise(Total = n())

ggplot(data = CombData1, aes(x=Date, y=Ratings, group=MarketSeg, color=MarketSeg)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~MarketSeg)
```

Thanks in advance.

Data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 
17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 
17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 
17044, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 
17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17074, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 
17105, 17105, 17105, 17105, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 
17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 
17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 
17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 17135, 
17135, 17135), class = "Date"), MarketCap = c(17793490000, 37606234252.4, 
2.1108e+10, 1309638615, 1.113e+10, 3397350000, 2652530240, 37091806405, 
1359499200, 6809300000, 76266899.28, 13774786240, 1545680000, 
63594722.73, 51341862.01, 50107136.47, 1.29e+09, 46223250, 128974374.6, 
3577976769.416, 3706781337, 11026283863.73, 5842461152.7, 4362690525, 
821145923.5, 238287420, 227040000, 131262000, 73756593.4, 77758200, 
73271825.2, 89201950, 24055716, 7815943725, 75117974128, 35904920250, 
1040640000, 17203972.5, 243725033, 275137500, 797503125, 2959027243, 
12806008832, 87684100, 1081800000, 251619858, 12771500000, 745577600, 
901299772.75, 97787904480, 1037369208, 269790000, 96921756.9, 
82668000, 363480200, 11028750000, 313985864.5, 2174677900, 765596013, 
72429837.39, 1065910694, 1324654600.8, 120852648578.5, 288792000, 
264450000, 165827845.298, 68080914610, 22072758675.4, 190250062289, 
2650279142.5, 93334060, 42901711525.4, 10427653484.6, 385600000, 
1381724307.15, 290812500, 29367359691, 14549176078.6, 248830003.2, 
793066396.5, 58800000, 14086361.16, 8761750000, 7733515000, 262440000, 
739680000, 8636728800, 1.28e+09, 8033914752, 42317532.63, 9663376.8, 
89517150, 2008211179.58, 1422750374.5, 233263043.52, 616047756.6, 
216763086, 483999180, 77497804.8, 18828151.2, 328728735, 6.27e+10, 
117600000, 3996340000, 371634938.745, 1.332e+09, 321133312.5, 
67716000, 115604797000, 71070174, 334599975, 1077300000, 170400000, 
67878383.2, 572400000, 352716000, 51949883424, 93762513621, 2421822652, 
313731880, 74698740600, 1.01772e+11, 17622500000, 360985600, 
15977500000, 4872145008, 507927000, 224770774, 554260125600, 
51077328972.6, 38632433, 5137500000, 17690700000, 37577980132, 
2.01e+10, 1322669845, 1.13e+10, 3386700000, 2521047060, 36000870922.5, 
1282459200, 6535100000, 72800222.04, 14776392320, 1432862000, 
58929472.8, 47415719.621, 43476908, 1.27e+09, 41416032, 104091858.6, 
3534532125.208, 3769080183, 11393974326.04, 5644411622.1, 4462246625, 
814971894, 239169966, 254100000, 133620000, 72896458.2, 74767500, 
81688183.5, 94192500, 15034822.5, 7716165720, 72621965494, 42379578000, 
1010830000, 13233825, 249669546, 276375000, 799912500, 3239810850, 
12182897664, 94959200, 1083600000, 292003292, 12617750000, 755452800, 
927965446.5, 104629033600, 977750288, 263160000, 65804771.79, 
75696000, 361630000, 10977750000, 311226762, 2350055150, 878472348.25, 
64650336.337, 1108358465, 1278175492, 120409559124.5, 270742500, 
269062500, 167940301.926, 67357931446, 21267861444.6, 205792725082, 
2615176107.5, 93536520, 43178369269, 12247597602.8, 424160000, 
1404375525.3, 290812500, 29224799692.5, 15307698168.1, 220318232, 
733721292, 51300000, 9328716, 8848500000, 7114833800, 270540000, 
753080000, 8434161600, 1.11e+09, 8536034424, 47942014.815, 10974835.08, 
84062700, 2076286134.82, 1465733769.5, 216692444.8, 629969739.8, 
218176758.3, 482694600, 82056499.2, 17833167.6, 298047386.4, 
6.2396e+10, 128800000, 4070190000, 369604146.73, 1.314e+09, 328084250, 
65407500, 112956396196, 63568322.3, 326381730, 1065960000, 1.92e+08, 
72918857.2, 587250000, 392616000, 53505742876.8, 103244116122, 
2449851782, 403369560, 64499735880, 93614400000, 17337500000, 
355699200, 15541750000, 5166831198, 515508000, 237105755.5, 487845513600, 
49462015406.4, 36267182, 5037500000, 17149700000, 37408455409.6, 
1.965e+10, 1316154230, 1.173e+10, 3.408e+09, 2449588810, 33579526315, 
1335360000, 6553380000, 69600212.28, 14568858720, 1423750000, 
59175012.27, 46207675.809, 45650753.4, 1.3e+09, 49181538, 111635430.34, 
3413507759.2, 3613333068, 10906673713.34, 5050263030.3, 4419579725, 
703839363, 241229240, 251790000, 137812000, 73111492, 75764400, 
83173423.2, 92506950, 16237608.3, 7815943725, 70957959738, 39358071050, 
1151750000, 9175452, 259554030.12, 282975000, 798707812.5, 3175014633, 
12161411072, 87301200, 1083600000, 333939935, 14749750000, 720889600, 
767971404, 93663106040, 977750288, 265200000, 153274185.36, 74700000, 
370040000, 1.1934e+10, 231764610), MarketSeg = c("Large", "Large", 
"Large", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Small", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Medium", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", "Medium", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Large", 
"Large", "Small", "Medium", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Small", "Medium", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Large", 
"Large", "Large", "Small", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Large", 
"Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Small", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", 
"Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Large", "Large", 
"Small", "Medium", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Large", 
"Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Small", "Medium", "Small", "Medium", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Large", "Large", 
"Large", "Small", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Large", 
"Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", 
"Large", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", "Small", 
"Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Small", 
"Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Large", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Large", "Small"), ESG = c("Not Rated", "Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", "Not Rated", 
"Not Rated")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -321L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(17044, 
17044, 17074, 17074, 17105, 17105, 17135, 17135), class = "Date"), 
    ESG = c("Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated", "Not Rated", 
    "Rated", "Not Rated", "Rated"), .rows = list(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 21L, 22L, 23L), c(2L, 8L, 20L), c(24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
    68L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
    82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
    94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
    106L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
    119L, 120L, 123L, 124L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
    135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
    146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 153L, 154L, 155L), c(35L, 
    50L, 63L, 67L, 69L, 77L, 102L, 109L, 117L, 118L, 121L, 122L, 
    125L, 129L, 130L, 134L, 140L, 152L), c(156L, 157L, 158L, 
    159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 168L, 169L, 
    170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
    180L, 181L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 
    191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 202L, 203L, 
    205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
    216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
    226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 235L, 236L, 
    237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 
    248L, 251L, 252L, 255L, 256L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 263L, 264L, 
    265L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 
    277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 285L, 286L, 287L
    ), c(167L, 182L, 195L, 199L, 201L, 204L, 209L, 234L, 241L, 
    249L, 250L, 253L, 254L, 257L, 261L, 262L, 266L, 272L, 284L
    ), c(288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
    297L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 
    308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 
    319L, 320L, 321L), c(299L, 314L))), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or:

```r
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, MarketSeg, ESG) %>%
  summarise(Total = n()) 

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Total, group=MarketSeg, color=MarketSeg, size = 'Rated')) + 
  geom_line(data = ~.x %>% summarise(Total=sum(Total)), aes(size='Total')) + 
  geom_line(data = ~.x %>% filter(ESG=='Rated')) +
  facet_wrap(~MarketSeg) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(.5, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Total number of obs
df <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date, MarketSeg) %>%
  summarise(Total = n())

# Number of rated obs
df1 <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date, MarketSeg, ESG) %>%
  summarise(Total = n()) %>% 
  filter(ESG == "Rated")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Total, group = MarketSeg, color = MarketSeg)) +
  geom_line(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Total, group = MarketSeg, lty = ESG), color = "red", size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~MarketSeg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>